# How to set default data in Django model fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to add an 'is_active' boolean, created_datetime and created_by fields to every model that I create.  Is there a way for me to let migrations handle that?  Basically adding to the existing addition of the Id field.

Comment: Just make a *abstract* base model, and then inherit this in the other models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to define an [*abstract base model* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeFIeld(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.Foreignkey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Next you can inherit this abstract base model in all your models:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    # …
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have these fields for each or an abstract base model to inherit these fields from:

```
is_active = BooleanField(default=True)
created_datetime = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
created_by = ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```